# Exposing application scripts to certain scripts only

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js

uhh it's hard to come with a right title for this problem excuse me.

In a backbone.js application i am building. Models, Views, Templates are all in **separate javascript, html files**. I want to export the Models, Views and Templates to the application bootstapper file (app.js) without polluting the global variable i.e doing `window.App.Model = myModel;` that. By export i mean make the code inside the files available to app.js for initialization and running

1. How do i go about doing this?
2. Are there any patterns that will solve the problem? Could you provide me a example

#### Description

In cases where models,views and templates are split to many disparate files the application bootstrapper file app.js should have some means to access these M,V,C components. Hence common approach is to do below inside the model.js file

```
window.App.Model.PersonModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

#### App.js

```
var instance = new window.App.Model.PersonModel();
var personView = new window.App.Views.PersonView({model:instance});
```

Finally you see that everything derives from the Global object `App` which i think is not safe, improper and weak way to build application dependencies

#### Suggestions

Just to the above question, could someone suggest a template loading library(javascript templates regardless of engine used) that can be used to load the templates

Comment: Can you explain better? What do you mean by "without polluting the global variable i.e doing window.App.Model = myModel; that."? Thanks

Comment: @DanieleB I added a description to the question itself , tell me if you want more

Comment: Can you elaborate on this: "which I think is not safe, improper and weak way to build application dependencies"?

Comment: Take a look on [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), which support  asynchronous module definitions/loading. You would have to rewrite your modules to and `app.js` to satisfy [AMD api](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html), but it would take only few strings of code.

Comment: @mickylaaaad Not safe - Someone who knows little js can alter my global variables ( for playing or to hack), app.js depends on models,views and collections and including these dependencies in order in html will suffice but that's bad practice. Weak in the sense it is susceptible to frequent changes and will break due to tight coupling

Comment: @vvd Any alternatives to require.js with all features of require.js ?

Comment: @Deeptechtons I don't understand whats not safe about it. You shouldn't be trusting any input from the client in your server app so it shouldn't matter if they alter their client side code

Comment: @Martin308 I Agree, but I expect a certain level of encapsulation to the `App` global variable this can only be possible by using something like requirejs or something.

Comment: @Deeptechtons require.js is the best available option if you don't want to switch to another MVC framework. What are you looking for in an alternative?

Comment: @ClarkPan I switched to require.js and it solved my problem. I hesitated a bit at start but now it looks awesome as a complete package. Thanks but the credit should go to vvd i suppose

Comment: Anyone who can modify App.js can modify any other variable in your code, and using requirejs will not prevent the need for App.js.

Comment: @vvd maybe you could add you comment as an answer so that this question can be marked answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), which support asynchronous module definitions/loading. You would have to rewrite your modules to and `app.js` to satisfy [AMD api](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html), but it would take only few strings of code.